# Android - Room - some user after migration without data

Tags: java, android, android-room

I have problem with my app in Java. After release new version of app some user send me info, that haven't any data in app. But in my reference mobile (where i have only version from google play) i have history data. Migration was about change data type (INT -> REAL) in Room DB.

So i don't know how discover where is problem - if still are date in DB but only not reachable or if data in DB are lost.

In firebase was some errors where we forgot change variables in code:

- error `Migration didn't properly handle:`)
- erro `Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number.`

-> so we released new version -> now in firebase we haven't any errors but still some user are without data.

Room version: **2.2.5** (*before release was 2.2.4*)

Did someone have similar issue? or can anybody advice "how to find where is problem" ?

EDIT:

Migration:

```java
static final Migration MIGRATION_6_7 = new Migration(6, 7) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            //create new table
            database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE work_days_new2 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, " + ...
"hour_salary_day  REAL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0, " + ...
);
            //copy old data into new table
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO work_days_new2 SELECT * FROM work_days ");

            //remove old table
            database.execSQL("DROP TABLE work_days");

            //rename the table
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE work_days_new2 RENAME TO work_days");

        }
    };
```

Model change for example form INT -> DOUBLE:

```java
@ColumnInfo(name = "hour_salary_day")
private double hourSalaryDay;
```

Thanks,

Comment: pls show your migration code and model you have been changed.

Comment: It seems as if you've pwned on the target system; the data corruption might be irreversible; at least while not being able to download the records into the table again; compare Firebase online backups (if any).